# onActivityResult in First Activity not returning result after finish second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

Activity A calls ActivityB using the following code

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, ActivityB), 1);
```

Activity B calls Activity c by:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, Activityc), 2);
```

I finish Activity C with return result and start new activity D there

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityD);
setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
finish();
```

I want to finish activity A and Activity B on get return result

but I am not getting return result. in this case

```
onActivityResult no calling in Activity A and Activity B
```

In short I want this function

```
btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent next = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityD.class);
                startActivity(next);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, next);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

I am only getting one thing of both. its going next activity or returing result back. I want going next activity with return result back simultaneously.

Comment: did you try with my code?

Comment: Yes. but that is different which i asking for,

Comment: I want this type function                                                                           Intent next = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(next);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, next);
                finish();

Comment: why you want to start activity all the time

Comment: bcz I want to lunch new activity with return result set

Comment: I have implemented SwiteBackLayout in my activity that display previous activity layout by swipe back. if not finish previous activity then it show while swipe that I dont want previous activity at that time. I want specific activity on swipe back.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not setting requestCode that is why you have this issue,try like this way

```
public final static int GO_FOR_COUNTRY = 11;
public final static int GO_FOR_STATE = 12;

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.register_country:
                Intent intents=new Intent(Registration.this,CountryList.class);
                startActivityForResult(intents, GO_FOR_COUNTRY);
                break;

            case R.id.register_state:
                Intent intentstate=new Intent(Registration.this,StateList.class);

                intentstate.putExtra("cids",cid);
                startActivityForResult(intentstate, GO_FOR_STATE);
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
```

and in you OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


            switch (requestCode)
            {

                case GO_FOR_COUNTRY:

                    try {

                       //your stuff
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case GO_FOR_STATE:

                    try {

                        //your stuff
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

            }



        }


    }
```

Comment: I already set setResult(RESULT_OK, next); but still not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve my problem but I couldn't found any where this. Actually Android activity not all to startActivity and return resultset simultaneously. So I need to manage it alternative way.